# Simple C program that will read the number of lines and will terminate once the EOF is entered by the user

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int read_next_line()
{
    int ch;
    int flag=0;
    ch=getchar();
    while(ch!= EOF && ch!='\n') {
        ch=getchar();
        flag=1;
    }
    return flag || (ch=='\n');
}
int read_all_lines()
{
    int linecount=0;
    int isvalid;
    while(!feof(stdin)) {
        isvalid=read_next_line();
        linecount=linecount + isvalid;
    }
    return linecount;
}

main {
    read_all_lines();
}
```

The above code gives an error saying main does not have a type. 
How to solve the problem ?

Comment: Please edit your code removing `enter code here` in order to increase readability

Comment: @Aryab : instaed of enter code here, put 4 spaces before eachh line of code to pretify

Comment: Please, edit your question, showing the full error you get.  Is it a runtime error, a compilation error, a linking error?  Thanks.. By the way, you have not declared a return type for `main` function.  It might be declared as `int main() { ...` at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`main` is a function that returns a value like other functions. It is up to you if it returns nothing `void main(void){ }` or an `int` value, `0` is returned in POSIX systems if no error encountered. More sophisticated but readable is to put `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);`.

```
int main(void){
  ...
}
```

Comment: Because usually the command `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` is not taught as first thing. It does not imply a pattern properly, but it is used when the programmer want to do some formal good-programming. If you do not think it is sophisticated, let me say that is for sophisticated programmers :)

Comment: It is not taught where? probably because the teacher is old fashioned like me and likes to teach C as it was developed chronologically, but that's not a sophisticated thing.  Threads are, for example, but a single constant no.  One of the first chapters in K&R introduces the constant EOF, and it has the same sophistication level than that one.

Comment: Right, it is not taught for first at the high school, and in noob level C courses. Actually the constant EOF is more privileged..maybe because in the next chapters (chars and strings) it is always used.

Answer (score 1):

The proper prototype in most environments is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

This means:

- `main()` is a function that returns an `int`.
- It has one argument called `argc` that is the number of command-line arguments.
- It has one argument called `argv` that is an array of those arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `int main()` instead of simply main

Answer (score 0):

Since C98 I think, C disallows to declare a function without using the return type for the result anymore.  You have to declare main as

```
int main ()
{
    ...
}
```

This is the minimum requirement to make your code compilable.  In previous releases of the C language, it was allowed to declare a function like you have done.  Implicitly, the compiler assumed it to be an `int` function without any complaint.  But, as for sure you have your compiler configured to compile post C98 or later code, it complaints with an error.  Previous versions of actual compilers issue normally a warning, telling you `main` will be assumed to be an `int` function, and this is to be able to compile *old* pre-ANSI code.

By the way, next time, don't limit yourself to explain what you have coded.  Cut and paste your actual code here, and also the exact error you got from the compiler (probably, it was only a warning, but you didn't include it, so we'll never know)  Probably the mistake is not where you think of, and that way saves us time and you the need of receiving this complaint.